# What Is More Expensive In Java? Serialization or Writing To a File?

Tags: java, serialization, file-io

I have a List of Strings I need to store locally (assume the list can run between 10 items to 100 items). I want to know if I should write the lists into a Flat database or use Serialization to flatten the object containing the list? Which is more expensive (CPU-wise)? What are the conditions that make one more expensive than the other?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why not try out and benchmark?

Comment: Even better, why not look at the other requirements and see what fits best with them?  The two choices tend to be used in different cases...who cares what's faster if it's a pain to work with?

Comment: if you're writing only 10-100 string than you might not even see any difference. Why are you so concerned with the performance for such a small dataset? Go with the simplest solution and change if it doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: This question just seems really misguided.  1) you haven't given the context of the scenario you care about (in what way and how often are these things going to be written/read).  2) you're asking about the CPU expense for something that is surely going to be limited by I/O throughput.  3) You haven't even explained your methodology for "flat database" (what operations does it need to support?) 4) Your title makes no sense (serialization often *involves* "writing to a file") This question seems to lack the details to make it answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a List of Strings I need to store locally (assume the list can run between 10 items to 100 items).

Assuming that the total length of the strings is small (e.g. less than 10K), the user-space CPU time used to do the saving is likely to be a few milliseconds using either serialization or a flat file.  In other words, it will be so fast that the user won't notice the difference.

You should be looking at the other reasons for choosing between the two alternatives (and others):

- How easy is it to write the code.
- How many extra dependencies does the alternative pull in.
- Human readability / editability of the saved data file ... in case you need to do this.
- How easy / hard it would be to change the "schema" of the stuff saved to file ... in case you need to do this.
- Whether you can update one string without rewriting the whole file ... if this is relevant.
- Support for other things such as atomic update, transactions, complex queries, etc ... if these are relevant.

---

And if, *despite what I said above*, you still want to know which will be faster (and by how much), then benchmark it.  The real world performance will depend on factors that you haven't specified.

Here are a couple of important references on how to write a Java benchmark so that it gives meaningful results.

- [How NOT to write a Java micro-benchmark](http://www.azulsystems.com/events/javaone_2002/microbenchmarks.pdf)
- [Robust Java benchmarking, Part 1: Issues.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-benchmark1/index.html)
- [Robust Java benchmarking, Part 2: Statistics and solutions](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-benchmark2/)

And you can experiment to answer this part of your question:

> What are the conditions that make one more expensive than the other?

(See above)

Answer (score 1):

Especially since they are Strings, just write them out one per line to a file.  Simple, fast, and far easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the expense but I believe since the object representation many a times contains whole lot of meta data (and structure) which might result in creating a big big object size than the original intended data. **Example** to this may be when you store a xml structure in a DOM object - it takes about 4X size in memory than the original data.

Based on above, I think serializing as an object might be more expensive. You may also want to consider the consumption of the end product. If you want the produced file to be human readable you will have to serialize the String data for readability.